# Creating coroutines to save users' data from redis to database after every user action in flask web-app

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I have a Flask web application based on websockets (I currently use flask-socketio). Also I have a **non-async** database (using flask-sqlalchemy) in which I store user's data. Database user table looks like:

| Id | username | password | clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John Doe | cc8b1415557f58abf2e2fa83c2ea6c91 | 5342 |

On a frontend I have a simple button. After each click websocket event handler is triggered and "clicks" field is incremented by 1.

Imagine if 10000 different users click that button **at once**. The load on the database will be enormous. To solve that problem i used **redis** to store user click counter. Redis key looks like:

```
user:0:clicks
```

Let the expiry time of *user:0:clicks* redis key be equal to *30 minutes*.

### Saving data from redis to database after specified time

Now we just need to save our redis data to the database before redis key expires. The solution is to **create coroutines which are used to save data from redis to database after delay**, which is less then key expiry time. In our case let's take a *25 minutes delay*.

To sum up, it works that way:

1. User clicks the button.
2. flask-socketio handler is triggered.
3. Redis user counter is incremented by 1. Expiry time is 30 minutes
4. The new saver coroutine is started. Coroutine delay is 25 minutes.
5. If user clicks again - expiry time is reset, coroutine is canceled and started again (or restarted).
6. If user doesn't perform any actions during 25 minutes - redis data is saved to a database using non-async method.

I've already developed some saver coroutine logic within a *RedisStateSaver class*. Here it is:

```py
import asyncio
import aioredis
from threading import Thread


class RedisStateSaver(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event_loop, db, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.loop = event_loop
        self.redis = aioredis.from_url(url, decode_responses=True)
        self.db = db

    def add_saver(self, redis_key, db_model, delay=1500):
        # Adding new saver
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.__save_after_delay(redis_key, db_model, delay), self.loop)

    async def __save_after_delay(self, redis_key, db_model, delay):
        # wait for 25 minutes here
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)

        # Getting redis data
        data = await self.redis.get(redis_key)
        
        # How to save data to database when database is not async?
        # await self.loop.run_in_executor(None, db_model.some_saving_method, data)
        # await asyncio.create_task(db_model.some_saving_method(data))

    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.loop.run_forever()
```

*Note that RedisStateServer class is a Thread, so the event_loop is also created inside that thread.*

And here the most unpleasant things appear:

1. db_model is a flask-sqlalchemy model, and it's not async. **How to properly call non-async database ORM methods from a *__save_after_delay* coroutine?**
2. Flask is not async at all, so i created a non-async *add_saver* function which creates a new coroutine for a specific user after each user click. *add_saver* method is called inside flask-socketio click handler. **Is it a good idea or are there better solutions to implement this inside my webapp?**

I also use unittests for my webapp. It is relevant to wait for all coroutines to finish after each unittest, so these coroutines need to be awaited:

```py
class TestSocketIO(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        # some non-async code here
    
    async def asyncTearDown(self):
        # awaiting for all pending coroutines
```

But in my code I only have futures (**not asyncio futures**) returned by *asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe*, and they can't be awaited. Using *concurrent.future.wait* causes blocking. The question is: how to properly await for coroutines launched with *asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe* method?

It would be nice to hear other suggestions about another implementations of everything that was described above. I also know that I can use Fast-Api which is fully asynchronous and stock asynchronous Sqlalchemy instead of flask-sqlalchemy, but rewriting all code is unaffordable due to time constraints.

Comment: Asyncio does not mix well with Flask/Flask-SQLAlchemy. I suggest you work within the sync style if you want to use Flask, or else you migrate your entire application to async, maybe with FastAPI or Quart.